# GWT 2.0 Themes?

Tags: java, css, gwt, themes

The default GWT themes are hideous. Does anyone know where a developer can find prepackaged themes that one can just 'drop' into an app and make the app look beautiful? Even worse, GWT 2.0's new Layout widgets [do not](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/67f02c599019a041) have any visual styling or themes.

Thanks,

JP

Comment: They don't allow theming? What happened to Google's "Don't be evil" mantra?

Comment: Can't you just change the CSS?

Comment: Tom: Yes, but I am not a CSS guru.

Answer (score 9):

Try this: http://works.sen-sei.in/gtg/

It's pretty basic, but it allows you to pick some colors then generates a GWT module in a .jar for you to include in your GWT project. Not as good looking as smartgwt or extjs, but a lot quicker.

Comment: Eclipse and java complain that the resulting jar file is corrupt.